# IE8 button's CSS "initial" value

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a responsive site which displays form buttons at the standard width at all monitor sizes, down to 481px, where after the width of the button is set to 100% of the containing div.

This works fine in all modern browsers with the following code:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px)
.button {
width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 769px)
.button {
width: initial;
}
```

As the CSS is mobile-first, "width: initial;" is resetting the button to the original size, exactly as I would like.

However IE8 doesn't recognise this, so it thinks "width: 100%;" is the button's width for all monitor sizes, causing the button to always span the page width. How would you get around this other than giving an absolute pixel value?

Comment: As a side-note: `width: initial;` is not valid. the initial value for `width` property is `auto`. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width).

Answer (score 1):

IE8 does not respect media queries you will need a polyfill script to add this functionality.

https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond